# Magento 2: How to add css class to body tag programmatically

Tags: magento2

I am trying to figure out how to add css class to body tag programmatically using Magento 2 framework

Answer (score 6):

You can add a class to the body from a block by overriding the `_prepareLayout` method:

```
public function _prepareLayout(){
    $this->pageConfig->addBodyClass('my-class');
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Comment: where is block?

Comment: Downvoted because you did not include the class. Ricardo's answer includes the class.

Comment: @NathanToombs - my answer does include the class and you know, was answered a YEAR before Ricardo's...

Answer (score 5):

I've created an observer to `layout_load_before` as follows:

```php
...
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $pageConfig
) {
    $this->_pageConfig = $pageConfig;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
     $this->_pageConfig->addBodyClass('my-new-body-class');
}
```

Comment: Correct event to watch for is "layout_load_before", not "load_layout_before".

Comment: Thanks @AfBu. I just fixed it.

Comment: It is also work with the controller_front_send_response_before && controller_action_predispatch_cms_index_index event

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code in layout to add css class or id to the body tag programmatically

```
   <body>
    <attribute name="class" value="custom-body-class" />
    <attribute name="id value="custom-html-id"/>
```

For example - open the file customer_account.xml in layout folder
    MagentoDir > vendor > magento > module-customer > view > frontend >layout

after open the customer_account.xml file you can see to add css class

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="account"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following example that I created, this plugin adds the store code to the body class: https://github.com/samgranger/StoreCodeBodyClass

Place the plugin in app/code/SamGranger and run the usual scripts to enable it (bin/magento module:enable SamGranger_StoreCodeBodyClass + bin/magento setup:di:compile).